# How does a class access a public method in another class in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and confused about how does a class access a public method in another class in C++. For example,

```
//.h of class A
class A {
public:
  void setDimension (int width, int height);
  A* obj;
}

//.cpp of class A
#include "A.h"
void A::setDimension (int width, int height) {
    // do some stuffs here
}

//.h of class B
#include "A.h"
class B {
public:
    void function ();
   //do something here
}

//.cpp of class B
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void B::function() {
     obj->setDimension(int width, int height);
}
```

And now I want the class B can access  the public method "setDimension" in class A. I think the dependency files are included, but when I run the program, I got an error says that `setDimension was not declared in this scope`. How can I call the setDimension method inside class B. Many thanks!

Comment: In your example **it won't**. setDimension() is an instance method then you need an object...

Comment: You need a class `A` instance to call its methods. Or `setDimension` should be static.

Comment: Take a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4115625)

Comment: firstly create an object from A  class.  `A a; a.setDimension(3, 5)`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check out [The definitive C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). There's little point in answering the q without pointing out that you need to look into OOP.

Comment: Note: with every answer given so far, the object of `A` will be murdered straight after calling `setDimension()` which i'd imagine renders the function pointless.

Comment: you nneed and instance of A in B, so you can call the public methods offered by A

Answer (score 5):

You have first to create an instance of object A and then call setDimension on this instance.

```
 //.cpp of class B
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void B::function() {
      A myInstance;
      myInstance.setDimension(10, 10);
}
```

Or you need to declare the method as static and can call it without instantiation:

```
//.h of class A
class A {
   public:
     static void setDimension (int width, int height);
}

 //.cpp of class B
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void B::function() {
     A::setDimension(10, 10);
}
```

If Class A is abstract:

```
//.h of class B
#include "A.h"
class B : A {
public:
    void function ();
}

//.cpp of class B
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void B::function() {
     this->setDimension(10, 10);
}
```

Comment: @Casius. Hi Casius, can I use the pointer, which I added in my question, to call the setDimension method?

Comment: @George yes, sorry, happens due to language hopping. You need to use  the scope resolution operator :: to call the static method.

Comment: @Xiufen Xu You didn't get the conecpt of OOP yet. If you want to use a pointer you have to create it in your function in B like A* obj; obj->setDimension(10, 10)

Comment: I am sorry that I forget to clarify the class A is an abstract class, so I think we cannot instantiate an object for A.

Comment: If A is abstract, you need to inherit it. Either in a third Class C or you can extend Class B.

Comment: @XiufenXu `this->` is redundant here, the only reason to call a function inherited from an abstract class using a pointer is generally to have the pointer in another class entirely. (There are exceptions with static and globals, although in all honesty I think you just need to get some good learning material), and as a side note, as of C++11, the scenarios where you'll want to use a so called naked pointer are few and far between.

Comment: @Casius. Got you! Thank you so much!

Comment: @George Your suggestions and materials are really helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `A` (and choose a particular width and height, or pass those in from somewhere) so that you can use its method

```
void B::function() {
   A mya;
   int mywidth = 10;
   int myheight = 20;
   mya.setDimension(mywidth, myheight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the method `setDimension(int width,int height);` in class A as static.

```
static void setDimension(int width,int height);

void B::function(){

    A::setDimension()

}
```

You access static member functions using the class name and the scope resolution operator `::`